# How to return a response from a pre config? (HapiJS)

Tags: routes, response, handler, hapi.js

I have the path:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/filesystem',
    config: {pre:[validateJWT]},
    handler: readDir
}
```

And two functions, the pre:

```
const validateJWT = async (req, res) => {
     . . .
    //returns true or false
}
```

And the handler:

```
const readDir = async(req, res) => {
  return res.response('Handler response').code(200);
};
```

How can I link the return value of the `validateJWT` function to use it in the `readDir` handler function?. Each function and the route are in different files.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the intended [authentication strategy](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/auth?lang=en_US) that Hapi provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the **validateJWT** function, you must assign a name to the function like this:

```
const validateJWT = () {
  return {
      method: async (req, _res) => {
        . . .
        //returns true or false
      },
      assign: 'validateJWT',
    };
}
```

And after doing this to retrieve the value of the function in readDir:

```
const readDir = async(req, res) => {
  // const {validateJWT} = req.pre;
  return res.response('Handler response').code(200);
};
```

DOC: https://hapi.dev/api?v=20.2.0#-routeoptionspre